# Проверка на последнюю цифру 9

Tags: java

Здравствуйте. В процессе работы пришлось проверять, является ли последняя цифра числа девяткой. Пока написал костыль

```
if(("" + num).endsWith("9"))
```

Как можно проверить математически? Диапазон [0, 99]

Comment: @AntonZikov число 18 делится на 9 без остатка, но на 9 не заканчивается

Comment: Да-да, я уже осознал свою глупость...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Например, так:

```
Math.abs(n) % 10 == 9
```

Если точно известно, что число положительное, можно не вычислять `Math.abs`.

Comment: Спасибо :) самое интересное что оператор `%` использовал, но в такой банальной задаче тупанул

Comment: @Flippy: Пожалуйста!

Answer (score 8):

Например  так:

```
public boolean endsWith9(int num) {
    return num % 10 == 9;
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

Более универсальное решение:

```
public static boolean isEndsWith(int value, int num) {
    return Integer.toString(Math.abs(value)).endsWith(Integer.toString(num));
}
```

Comment: Если вы уж пользуетесь `toString`, может быть, проще тогда исходное число привести к строке, и проверять, оканчивается ли эта строка на то, что нужно?

Comment: @VladD Можно и так :)